# Regular Expression: Double Backslashes in Bracket Expression

Tags: regex

What do the double backslashes in the following expression match?

```
/^[\\?]/
```

Is it a filter for `\` and `&` (escaped backslash) - or - `\\` and `&` (not escaped) - or - `\` and `?` (escaped question mark)?

Comment: You can check it by trying to match some sample strings and see whether there is a match or not.

Comment: A single backslash means escape, so a second one after it gets escaped, meaning the double backslash matches a single backslash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a link to your regular expression along with some example test strings, as tested in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Jrw1G4YLtT).

The `^` at the start of your regular expression anchors what you are about to match for to the beginning of your test string.

Following that is brackets `[]`, which means any of the characters within the brackets can be matched for.

Inside the brackets, you have a `\\` - the first `\` escapes the character that is following - meaning you want to search for whatever is about to follow that `\`.  It just so happens that what follows is another `\` - so that means one of the characters you will accept is a `\`.

Following that is a question-mark `?` - which, when placed inside brackets, literally means you want to match for the question-mark symbol.

So, your regular expression is looking for any string that begins with either a backslash or a question-mark.

Again, please reference the [example test strings at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Jrw1G4YLtT).

Answer (score 1):

`\` escapes special characters to literal and literal characters to special. E.g: `/\(s\)/` matches '(s)' while `/(\s)/` matches any whitespace and captures the match (from [javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)). Since `\` is a special character, you have to escape it order to search a backslash in a string :

```
var s = '\\ must be escaped in a string as well!';
/\./.test(s);  // false
/\\./.test(s); // true
```