# pattern regex ignoring back slash for quotes and single quote

Tags: android, regex

I am using following pattern,

```
public static final String DEGREE_SIGN = "°";
 public static final Pattern DMS = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(-?\\d{1,3})\\s*" + DEGREE_SIGN
            + "+\\s*(\\d{1,2})\\s*\'"
            + "+\\s*(\\d{1,2}\\.+?\\d{0,6})\\s*\"+$");
```

And trying with string as `"38° 53' 23\""`

```
Matcher m = DMS.matcher(latitudeDMSString);
                if (m.find())
                {
}
```

However its failing. In debug I can see regex as

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=^\s*(-?\d{1,3})\s*°+\s*(\d{1,2})\s*'+\s*(\d{1,2}\.+?\d{0,6})\s*"+$ region=0,11 lastmatch=]
```

It seems to be removing `\` infront of `'` and `"` How can I fix this

> public static final Pattern DMS =
>   Pattern.compile("^\s*(-?\d{1,3})\s*°+\s*(\d{1,2})\s*\'+\s*(\d{1,2}\.?\d{1,4}?)\s*\"+$");

Comment: it is because, the backslash acts as an escape character-> https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Backslash-Escapes.html

Comment: also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21829037/6142219

Comment: @Deepakkaku yes i know its an escape character that is why its placed there. Shouldn't it fixes the problem? What fix do you suggest

Comment: It seems to be removing \ infront of ' -> because its an escape character, if you need that backslash then use \\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this part in your regex:

```
\\.+?
```

to

```
\\?
```

Basically you are trying to make dot optional and using `\.+?` just makes it a lazy match 1+ times.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FkWtHe/1)

Comment: Yes I forgot to remove + and thought quotes were causing the issue. Thanks for that

Comment: I want to make it so it will detect 1-3 digits and if decimal is placed then it should check upto 6 digits. How will I modify this,

Comment: Can you please provide example inputs for these

Comment: 38° 53' 23\" or 38° 53' 23.02342\" should pass  38° 53' 23.02342a\" should fail

Comment: Your current regex is already matching `38° 53' 23\"` and `38° 53' 23.02342\"` and rejecting `8° 53' 23.02342a\"`

Comment: Check my new regex, it is compiling the one with decimal but not without decimal. For some reason it is compiling fine on the website.

Answer (score 0):

In java following are the escape characters:-

- \' Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
- \" Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
- \ Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

Therefore, in order to use \' and \" in a string in java, we need to escape those characters by using \\\' and \\\" respectively.